# Laravel session destroyed on page refresh

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.7

I have an admin panel that I protect with user authentication. Once I try to access it, it redirects me to the login form, which uses the 'guest' middleware (this is the expected behaviour).
Once I attempt to log in it works like a charm, redirects me to the admin dashboard and the Auth object is created (I can retrieve the name).
However, if I click on any link inside of the panel, or press F5, it redirects me back to the login form. For the sake of testing what happened, I removed the 'auth' middleware protection from the admin panel, and it gives me an error when I try to retrieve the Auth::user()->name property.

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

So I am assuming that it destroys the Auth object on every page refresh, what I don't understand is where this behaviour comes from.
I am using the default Auth middlewares, with the LoginController provided in the documentation (with some tweaks):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Authentication;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request){
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $remember = $request->input('remember');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }

    public function index(){
        return view('auth.login');
    }
}
```

All of the routes in the admin panel are inside a group in my routes file:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    //All of the admin routes here
});
```

The login route is protected by the 'guest' middleware, so no authenticated user can access the login form.

Please ask me to post any code that you think could be helpful, I'm fairly new to Laravel and don't really know what to post.

Comment: It could be that the session is not persisted. Please check that the ```driver``` in ```config/session.php``` is not array. More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session

Comment: In order to use `Auth::user()->name` you need to use the namespace `Auth;` e.g.: `use Auth;`

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez `driver` is set as _file_ : `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')`, and the files are actually inside of the storage/framework/sessions folder.

Comment: @Patrick I am using it already. That is not the problem because it is working the first time. I login, it redirects me to the admin page (and it displays the user name, so it's working fine). The problem is when I refresh the page or try to navigate to a different route, it appears to eliminate the session and redirects me to the login form again.

Comment: Is there any special reason you don't use the default `Auth::routes();` and the default `LoginController` generated when you run `php artisan make:auth`?

Comment: @nakov I needed to customize the routes, and I have to create permissions so only the administrators can access the admin panel (although I haven't done that yet). But I followed the documentation in regard with these topics.

Comment: @AlejandroOteroGómez I would suggest you do that using a custom middleware instead of completely rewriting the auth forms.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It was just a rookie mistake. I had the `Auth::logout()` function in the href property of a link, thinking it would trigger when someone clicked it. Instead, it logged me out as soon as the page loaded, that's why there was a session just the first time.